# What is the equivalent of using hiera as an ENC in Ansible?

Tags: ansible, hiera

I use hiera as an External Node Classifier in Puppet in order to avoid that roles are deployed on nodes that are for example incompatible. Now I have two servers that are provisioned using Ansible. I am concerned that when the cluster grows that I have to check what nodes are available and then decide what role should be applied instead of hiera that that is doing automatically. For example, system A is a developer system and deploy development role and systemB is a db system deploy database role.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ansible supports pulling host and group variables from one or more [external inventory systems](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/intro_dynamic_inventory.html). Examples are included of pulling in inventory from Cobbler, EC2 and OpenStack. Ansible Tower also includes its own dynamic inventory source. It is also possible to [write your own script](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/developing_inventory.html) to pull data from any source.